# What's the difference between /dev/sda1 and /dev/xvda1?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The Linux Operating System uses /dev/sda1, /dev/xvda1, etc., to identify block storage devices.  From looking at their names, what's the difference between these two devices?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/dev/sda` device is provided for support of legacy devices and installations that don't understand Xen native virtual disks.  The `/dev/xvda1` device is the native device and the one you should use.